# how to disable "save as" and "print" option of browser

Tags: browser

Can any one tell me how to disable "save as" and "print" option of browser menu bar?
if I go through File->Save As or Print, the document gets printed and saved.

I want to prevent this.

Can any one help me out in this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
body {display:none;}
}
</style>
```

The above code can be used to disable the user from printing the webpage.I have tested this code, its working fine for me in IE8, Chrome and Firefox.