# how to restrict user not to perform browser "save as" , "print" action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

For restricting a user to print a answer is given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022310/how-to-disable-save-as-and-print-option-of-browser)..

how it can be handled for save as?

Comment: Didnt get what you are trying to say . i cant guess.

Comment: Don't allow them to access your page via a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Save-As-Feature is handled by browsers differently. Some just copy their cached files, some make a new request and rewrite up files to a local structure. **It IS possible to undergo every protection you might think of!**

But, if you really care, you can at least make it a little less easy to save your content with  some javascript and css hacks. (see [this link also suggested](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/512445-code-disable-print-save))

1. **disable printing** by setup a print-stylesheet with *{display:none} - very annoying for the user, but works
2. **disable the right mouse-button**, to not let the user see your source - very, very annoying, and most actions can be used via the browser navigation menu.
3. **disable the clipboard** - most users won't see that "feature", but it works.
4. **disable the save-as** by dynamic loading of content could work in some browsers. for doing this, you have to present a page with just javascript (or at least a header, footer, etc) that loads the content of your page with ajax on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You can not restrict what a user does with your content once it is on their computer.  Even the CSS hack linked in that question is easily defeated.

If they want to save it to disk, print it, fold it, spindle it or mutilate it, they have that ability and there is nothing you can to to effectively stop them.